# Mongo no me conecta a localhost

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Hola tengo aqui todo el codigo de js, intento hacer node index.js y no me conecta al servidor, por lo tanto no puedo abrir robo 3t alguna idea? hago mongod y nada.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
//DEPENDENCIES
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongoOperations = require('./mongoOperations');

//CONNECT TO DB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/random-movies', function(err){
if (err) console.log('Not able to connect: ' + err.message);
console.log('Connected to database RANDOM-MOVIES');
});


//CREATE USERS
mongoOperations.createMovies();
mongoOperations.findMovie();

//DELETE USERS
// mongoOperations.deleteMovies();
 
 
 
 
 
var names = ['Aarón','Abd al-Aziz','Abdías','Abdón','Abdul Latif','Abdullah','Abel','Abelardo','Abelardo','Abraham','Absalón','Abundio','Acacio','Achiuta','Acisclo','Adalberón','Adalberto','Adán','Adelardo','Adem','Adinath','Adolfo','Adrián','Adrista','Afrodisio','Agamenón','Agapito','Agastia','Agatoclio','Aghásura','Agni','Agustín','Aitor','Aladino','Alarico','Albano','Alberto','Albino','Alcibíades','Alcide','Alcides','Aldo','Alec','Alejandro','Alejo','Alfonso','Alfredo','Alois','Álvaro','Amadeo','Amado','Amador','Amancio','Amara-kosha','Ambarisha','Ambarisha','Ambarisha','Ambrosio','Amenhotep','Américo','Amílcar','Amit','Amós','Amsha','Anacleto','Ananías','Anastasio','Anatole','Anatolio','Ander','Andhaka','Andoni','Andrei','Andrés','Andrónico','Ángel','Aníbal','Aniceto','Anselmo','Antenor','Antoni','Antonino','Antonio','Āpastamba','Apolinar','Apolo','Apolonio','Aquiles','Argimiro','Aristarco','Arístides','Aristóteles','Arjuna','Armand','Armando','Arnaldo','Arnau','Arnulfo','Arquímedes','Arsenio','Arturo','Aruná','Aryaman','Ascanio','Asdrúbal','Ashuatama','Aśoka','Astika','Asura','Ashuin','Atanasio','Augurio','Augusto','Aureliano','Aurelio','Avelino','Axel','Bakasura','Bala Krisna','Balarama','Balbino','Baldomero','Balduino','Baltasar','Banásura','Bartolomé','Basilio','Baudhāyana','Bautista','Beato','Belisario','Beltrán','Benedetto','Benedicto','Benigno','Benito','Benjamín','Bento','Berengario','Bernabé','Bernardino','Bernardo','Bernhard','Bernie','Berto','Betuel','Bhaga','Bhajan','Bharadvaya','Bharata','Bhavaviveka','Bhima','Bhishmá','Bhrigu','Biagio','Bienvenido','Blas','Bobo','Bogdan','Bogumil','Bogusław','Boleslao','Boni','Bonifacio','Borja','Bosco','Boutros','Boyan','Braulio','Brian','Brijadratha','Brihaspati','Bronisław','Bruno','Burgess','Calixto','Camilo','Cancio','Cándido','Canek','Canuto','Carlos','Carmelo','Casimiro','Casio','Casiodoro','Casto','Cayetano','Cayo','Cecilio','Ceferino','Celedonio','Celestino','Celso','César','Chandra','Cháraka','Chiávana','Cipriano','Ciriaco','Ciriaco','Cirilo','Ciro','Claudio','Clemente','Columbano','Columbano','Conrado','Constancio','Constantino','Cornelio','Corono','Cosme','Crescencio','Crisanto','Crisóstomo','Crispín','Cristián','Cristóbal','Dadhichi','Daksha','Dalmacio','Dalmacio','Dámaso','Damián','Daniel','Danijel','Danilo','Dardo','Darío','Dasharatha','David','Demetrio','Demi','Deodato','Deogracias','Desiderio','Devabhuti','Devala','Diego','Dieus','Dimas','Dimas','Diodoro','Dionisio','Dobromir','Domingo','Donato','Doroteo','Dritarastra','Drona','Drupada','Durvasa','Duryodhana','Edelmiro','Edgar','Edmundo','Eduardo','Edwin','Eero','Efraím','Efraín','Egidio','Eleazar','Eleuterio','Elías','Eliseo','Eloy','Emerico','Emeterio','Emigdio','Emiliano','Emilio','Enoc','Enós','Enrique','Enzo','Epifanio','Erasmo','Eric','Ernesto','Esaú','Esdras','Espartaco','Esprit','Estanislao','Esteban','Etelfrido','Ethelbaldo','Eudes','Eugenio','Eulogio','Eusebio','Eustaquio','Evangelista','Evaristo','Ezequiel','Fabián','Fabio','Fabricio','Facundo','Faustino','Fausto','Federico','Feliciano','Felipe','Félix','Fermín','Fernando','Fidel','Fidel','Filemón','Finnian','Fiódor','Florencio','Florentino','Florián','Forrest','Fortunato','Francisco','Froilán','Fructuoso','Fulgencio','Gabino','Gabriel','Gamaliel','Gana','Gandharva','Ganesha','Garga Muni','Garuda','Gaspar','Gastón','Gaudencio','Gautama','Gedeón','Geoffrey','George','Gerardo','Germán','Germán','Germano','Gerson','Gervasio','Gianluca','Gianni','Gilberto','Ginés','Ginés','Gisbert','Gobrias','Godofredo','Goliat','Gonzalo','Gopala','Gorō','Aksapada Gótama','Gottlieb','Govinda','Gregorio','Gritsa Madá','Guido','Guillén','Guillermo','Gumaro','Gustavo','Guy','Hamza','Haroldo','Harry','Hassan','Héctor','Heihachi','Heihachirō','Heinz','Heliodoro','Henrik','Henrique','Henrique','Heráclides','Heraclio','Hercle','Hércules','Heriberto','Herman','Hermann','Hermenegildo','Herodes','Higinio','Hilario','Hipólito','Hisashi','Homero','Homobono','Honorato','Honorio','Horacio','Horatio','Hormisdas','Huberto','Hugo','Humberto','Iaksa','Ichirō','Ignacio','Iker','Iksuaku','Indalecio','Isaac','Isaak','Isaías','Isidoro','Isidro','Ismael','Israel','Italo','Iudistira','Iván','Ivo','Izan','Jacinto','Jacobo','Jael','Jaganatha','Jaime','Jair','Jairo','Jalaiuda','Janto','Jarischandra','Javier','Jean-François','Jean-Pierre','Jeffrey','Jemachandra','Jenaro','Jeremías','Jerónimo','Jirania Kashipú','Jirō','Joachim','Joaquín','Job','Joel','Johann','Jorge','José','José Luis','José María','Joseba','Josefino','Josías','Josmar','Jossmar','Josu','Josué','Juan','Juan Bautista','Juanelo','Juantxo','Judá','Julián','Julio','Kailash','Kalidasa','Kankurō','Kanua','Kardama','Karttikeya','Kavi','Kedara','Kedarnath','Kemuel','Kenneth','Kenzō','Kepa','Kinnara','Kintarō','Kintuillang','Kojirō','Koldobika','Ksatri','Kumbhá Karna','Kuru','Kushika','Labán','Ladislao','Lain','Lalo','Laureano','Lautaro','Lázaro','Leandro','Leonardo','Leopoldo','Leví','Licas','Lior','Loïc','Lokapala','Lorenzo','Lubomir','Lucas','Ludovico','Ludovico','Luis','Madhusudan','Maffeo','Maia Asura','Majá','Malcolm','Mamerto','Mansur','Manu','Manuel','Marcelino','Marcelo','Marcos','Mariano','Mario','Martín','Matariswan','Mateo','Mauricio','Mázatl','Medardo','Miguel','Mikel','Miqueas','Mirko','Miroslav','Modesto','Moritz','Mstislav','Muawiya','Muhammad','Mustafá','Nahuel','Nahum','Nala','Námaste','Nandi','Narakasura','Natán','Nataraja','Nath','Nehemías','Nelson','Nepomuk','Néstor','Nicolás','Nikita','Nimi','Níriti','Noé','Norberto','Odón','Oier','Omar','Onesíforo','Ordoño','Orlando','Óscar','Osmar','Osvaldo','Oswaldo','Pablo','Panagiotis','Pándava','Pandú','Pánfilo','Pantaleón','Paolo','Parashurama','Pariksit','Parsuá','Paryania','Pascual','Patricio','Pedro','Philippe','Pol','Pradiumna','Premislao','Primitivo','Prisciliano','Prithú','Prudencio','Publio','Pulaja','Puloman','Púrusha','Purushottama','Quirico','Radomir','Radosław','Rafael','Raghú','Raimundo','Rainer','Raju','Ráksasa','Rama','Raúl','Ravana','Regis','Remigio','Renato','René','Reto','Reza','Ribhu','Ricardo','Rigoberto','Rinchen Gyaltsen','Rishabha','Rishikesh','Roberto','Rodolfo','Rodrigo','Rogelio','Roger','Roland','Rosendo','Saburō','Sadrac','Sagara','Sajádeva','Sakya Trizin','Salomón','Salvador','Sambor','Samuel','Sancho','Sanjaya','Santiago','Sanyaia','Šarūnas','Satrayit','Saúl','Sebastián','Selim','Laksman Sen','Senén','Sergio','Shalivájana','Adi Shankara','Shinzō','Shirō','Shiva','Siddha','Sidonio','Amara Simja','Simón','Slavko','Slawomir','Srivatsa','Stefano','Sudraka','Sukra','Suleimán','Suyog','Taichi','Takumi','Tal','Tiberio','Timoteo','Tinia','Tito','Tobías','Togarma','Tomás','Tonatiuh','Toussaint','Tuastri','Ubaidallah','Ubaldo','Uranius','Urbano','Urbano','Urías','Uriel','Urso','Václav','Vadim','Vairochana','Vaiu','Vajrapani','Vala','Valerio','Valéry','Vali','Vanaspati','Jarsha Vardhana','Vasudeva','Vasudeva','Vicente','Víctor','Vidura','Vikramāditya','Vishua Karma','Visnú','Vito','Vladimiro','Vladislao','Vsévolod','Warren','Wenceslao','William','Wojciech','Xicohténcatl','Yada Bharata','Yajnú','Yanameyaiá','Yaromir','Yasu','Yasunari','Yazid','Yogui','Yusuf','Yves','Zabulón','Zacarías','Zanobi','Zaqueo','Zbigniew','Zeferino','Zoran'];
let lastnames=['Abad','Abalos','Abarca','Abendano','Abila','Abina','Abitua','Aboites','Abonce','Abrego','Abrica','Abrigo','Abundis','Aburto','Acebedo','Acebes','Acencio','Acero','Acevedo','Aceves','Acha','Adan','Adrian','Agirre','Agredano','Aguado','Aguallo','Aguas','Aguayo','Agueda','Aguero','Aguila','Aguilar','Aguilera','Aguinaga','Aguino','Aguirre','Agundis','Ahuatl','Ahumada','Aiala','Aillon','Alamilla','Alamiya','Alamo','Alanis','Alarcon','Canpos','Canseco','Cansino','Cantero','Cantu','Canuu','Canzeco','Capasete','Capetillo','Capistrano','Capitan','Caquihui','Cara','Carabajal','Caraballo','Carabantes','Carabaxal','Carandia','Carapia','Carasco','Caravajal','Caravallo','Caravantes','Cardenas','Cardiel','Cardona','Cardoso','Cariaga','Carillo','Carion','Carlin','Carlon','Carlos','Carmel','Carmona','Carnero','Caro','Carpintero','Carpio','Carrales','Carranco','Carrasco','Carreno','Carrera','Carreto','Carrillo','Carrion','Carrisal','Carrisales','Carriyo','Carrizal','Carro','Carvajal','Casa','Casanoba','Casanova','Casares','Casas','Casasola','Casayu','Casco','Caseres','Casian','Casillas','Casimiro','Casique','Cassas','Cassillas','Castanon','Castelan','Castellanos','Castellon','Casteneda','Castilla','Castilleja','Castillo','Castiyo','Casto.','Castorena','Castrejon','Castrillo','Castro','Catalan','Catano','Catuta','Cavallero','Cavazos','Cavello','Cavrera','Cayetano','Cayo','Cazares','Ceballos','Cedeno','Cedillo','Ceja','Celaya','Celio','Celis','Cena','Centeno','Cepeda','Cerbantes','Cerda','Cermeno','Cerna','Ceron','Cerrano','Cerrato','Cerrillo','Certuche','Cervantes','Cervera','Cervin','Cevallos','Cevilla','Chabaria','Chabarin','Chabarria','Chabes','Chabira','Chaboya','Chaca','Chacon','Chagolla','Chagollan','Chaire','Chantes','Chapa','Chapul','Charles','Charqueno','Chavarria','Chavarrieta','Chaves','Chaveste','Chavez','Chavira','Chavolla','Chia','Chica','Chico','Chicuate','Chihuagua','Chihuahua','Chilaca','Chilar','Chilchotl','Chiquito','Chirinos','Cholico','Cholula','Chon','Choperena','Cierra','Cifuentes','Cilba','Cilva','Cimental','Cirilo','Cisneros','Cistos','Clark','Claudio','Clemente','Cleto','Climaco','Coatl','Coba','Cobarrubias','Cobian','Cobos','Coca','Cochi','Cocio','Cocone','Cocusi','Coeto','Coghi','Coix','Colchado','Colima','Colin','Colirio','Collado','Colmenares','Colmenero','Colorado','Colunga','Comparan','Compean','Concepcion','Condado','Conde','Conrrique','Constancia','Constante','Constantino','Contreras','Conuu','Copado','Coquau','Coquihui','Corales','Corchado','Cordoba','Cordova','Corea','Coreno','Coria','Cornejo','Cornelio','Corona','Coronado','Corral','Corrales','Correa','Corro','Cortes','Cortez','Cos','Cosa','Cosileon','Cosme','Costilla','Cota','Cotzomi','Covarrubias','Covarruvias','Covos','Cox','Coyaso','Coyo','Coyote','Coyotl','Coz','Cozatl','Cozileon','Crespin','Crespo','Crisanto','Crisostomo','Crispin','Cristan','Crus','Cruz','Cuachitl','Cuacitl','Cuacuil','Cuadros','Cuaetle','Cuatecatl','Cuatlat','Cuatlayol','Cuautle','Cuautli','Cuaya','Cuechi','Cuello','Cuenca','Cuesta','Cuevas','Cueyar','Cueyo','Cuin','Cumplido','Cura','Cusicuiy','Cusihuidzu','Cusihuiyo','Cusimahu','Cusimau','Cusimey','Cusinuu','Cusiquihui','Cusisayu','Cusituta','Dabalos','Dabila','Dado','Damian','Daniel','Dasa','Davila','Daza','Delara','Delgadillo','Delgado','Delos','Delossantos','Deras','Diego','Dimas','Dionicio','Dios','Dolores','Domingues','Dominguez','Donate','Dongu','Dorado','Dorantes','Duarte','Duenas','Duque','Duran','Duron','Echeverria','Eledesma','Elenes','Elias','Elisondo','Elizarraras','Elizondo','Enamorado','Encarnacion','Encinas','Enciso','Enriquez','Enrrique','Enrriquez','Ensiso','Eredia','Erera','Ernandes','Errera','Escalante','Escalera','Escamilla','Escandon','Escobar','Escobedo','Escojido','Escovar','Escutia','Espalin','Espana','Esparcia','Esparza','Espejo','Espindola','Espinel','Espinola','Espinoza','Espiritu','Espitia','Esqueda','Esquibel','Esquibias','Esquivel','Esquivias','Esteban','Estebes','Estevan','Esteves','Estrada','Estrella','Estreya','Estudillo','Europa','Evangelista','Evans','Evora','Fabela','Fabian','Facio','Fajardo','Falcon','Farfan','Farias','Faustino','Faxardo','Feliciano','Felis','Feliz','Ferel','Fermin','Fernandes','Fernandez','Fernando','Ferreira','Ferrel','Fierro','Figueroa','Filoteo','Fiscal','Fletes','Flores','Florez','Fonceca','Fonseca','Frade','Fraga','Fragoso','Fraide','Fraile','Franca','Francisco','Franco','Frausto','Fregoso','Frias','Frutos','Fuente','Fuentes','Fuerte','Fulgencio','Funes','Gabia','Gabino','Gabriel','Gadillo','Gado','Galabis','Galan','Galarza','Galas','Galavis','Galban','Galbes','Galego','Galicia','Galisia','Gallardo','Gallega','Gallegos','Gallo','Galvan','Galvana','Gama','Gamboa','Gamero','Games','Gamez','Gamino','Ganboa','Gandara','Gaona','Garambuyo','Garate','Garavito','Garay','Garcia','Gardea','Garduno','Garfias','Garia','Garibai','Garibaldo','Garibay','Garivay','Garnica','Garrido','Garsa','Garsia','Garza','Garzia','Gasca','Gascon','Gaspar','Gastan','Gatica','Gauna','Gausin','Gavia','Gavilan','Gavilanes','Gavino','Gayardo','Gayo','Gaytan','Gazca','Gebara','George','Gerardo','Gerero','German','Gerra','Gertrudis','Gervacio','Ghco','Ghcuaa','Ghcuiy','Ghcusi','Ghghu','Ghichi','Ghico','Ghicuau','Ghicuey','Ghicuiy','Ghicusi','Ghighi','Ghighu','Ghihuaco','Ghihuidzu','Ghihuiyo','Ghima','Ghinoo','Ghiquau','Ghisa','Ghisayu','Ghituta','Ghiyo','Ghma','Ghmahu','Ghmau','Ghmey','Ghnoo','Ghnuu','Ghquihui','Ghsa','Ghsayu','Ghsichi','Ghsighi','Ghsima','Ghsisa','Ghsiyo','Ghtuta','Ghyo','Gil','Gillen','Gimenes','Gimenez','Gines','Gloria','Gobea','Goche','Godina','Godines','Godoi','Godoy','Gomes','Goncales','Gongora','Gonzaga','Gonzalez','Gopar','Gordillo','Gordo','Govea','Gracia','Gradilla','Grageda','Grajales','Grajeda','Granado','Grande','Grangenal','Grano','Grasia','Gregorio','Griego','Grigalva','Grijalva','Grusiaga','Guadalaxara','Guadalupe','Guadarrama','Guadiana','Guajardo','Guanajuato','Guaracha','Guardado','Guardia','Guardiola','Guarneros','Gudino','Guereca','Guerra','Guerrero','Guerta','Guete','Guevara','Guia','Guido','Guijarro','Guillen','Guilo','Guimenes','Guines','Guipe','Guisa','Guisar','Guiterres','Guiza','Gurrola','Gusman','Gutieres','Gutierrez','Haro','Harris','Haumada','Helguera','Henrique','Henriquez','Heredia','Hererra','Hermoso','Hernandes','Hernandez','Herrada','Herrera','Herver','Hibarra','Hierro','Higareda','Higuera','Hijar','Hilario','Hinojosa','Hornelas','Horosco','Horta','Hortega','Hortis','Huaracha','Huerta','Huisache','Huisar','Huitzil','Huizar','Humada','Hurtado','Hurvina','Hydalgo','Ianes','Ianito','Ibarra','Idalgo','Illescas','Infante','Inigues','Inojos','Inojosa','Isarraras','Ivarra','Jacinto','Jaco','Jacoba','Jacobo','Jaen','Jahuey','Jalpa','Jamaica','Jan','Jaques','Jara','Jaramillo','Jaramiyo','Jarquin','Jaso','Jaure','Jauregui','Jauri','Jazo','Jimenes','Jiron','Jonguitud','Juache','Juan','Juares','Jurado','Labra','Labrador','Ladino','Ladron','Lagunas','Lagunillas','Lala','Lamas','Lambarena','Landa','Landeros','Landeta','Landin','Langarcia','Langarica','Larios','Laris','Laro','Lasareno','Laso','Laureano','Lazareno','Lazaro','Lazo','Leal','Leandro','Leche','Lechuga','Leiba','Lemus','Leon','Leonardo','Leonor','Lepe','Lerma','Lesama','Leso','Letins','Levario','Leyba','Liebanos','Liera','Ligas','Lilo','Limon','Linan','Linares','Lino','Lira','Lisama','Lisarde','Lisarraga','Lisea','Lisola','Lisondo','Llaguno','Llamas','Llanas','Llanes','Llanito','Llepes','Loayza','Lobato','Lobos','Loeza','Lomas','Lomeli','Lomelin','Longoria','Lopez','Loredo','Lorenzana','Lorenzano','Lorenzo','Loreto','Loria','Losada','Losano','Lossano','Lovato','Loya','Loza','Lozada','Luciano','Lucio','Luengas','Luevano','Lueza','Luga','Lugarda','Luguin','Lujan','Lule','Lumbreras','Luna','Lupercio','Lupez','Lupian','Luria','Luz','Macario','Macedo','Machado','Machorro','Macias','Maciel','Madaleno','Madera','Madrigal','Madrueno','Mafra','Magallanes','Magallon','Magana','Magdaleno','Maguellal','Maia','Maiorga','Malacara','Maldonado','Maleno','Malindo','Malo','Malpica','Mancera','Mancha','Mancilla','Mandujano','Mani','Manriquez','Mansanales','Mansanares','Mansanero','Mansano','Mansilla','Manso','Mantilla','Manuel','Manzanales','Manzanares','Manzo','Marabilla','Maravilla','Marceleno','Marchan','Marcial','Mareno','Mares','Marfil','Margues','Maria','Mariano','Marimon','Marin','Marines','Marroquin','Marrufo','Martel','Martin','Martines','Martinon','Mascorro','Massias','Mata','Mateo','Mateos','Matheo','Mathias','Matias','Maturan','Maya','Mayor','Meave','Meda','Medel','Medellin','Medero','Medez','Medina','Medinilla','Megia','Mejia','Mejicano','Mejorada','Melecio','Melendres','Melesio','Melgar','Melgarejo','Melgoza','Mellado','Membrila','Mena','Menchaca','Mendes','Mendez','Mendia','Mendieta','Mendiola','Mendosa','Meneces','Meneses','Meras','Mercado','Merced','Mereles','Merino','Merlin','Merlo','Merodio','Mesquite','Messa','Mexia','Meza','Michaca','Miguel','Milan','Minchaca','Minero','Minguela','Minxares','Mira','Miramontes','Miranda','Mireles','Mitzi','Moctesuma','Modesto','Mogica','Moia','Mojica','Molina','Molla','Molleda','Monares','Moncada','Moncayo','Mondragon','Monjaras','Monreal','Montana','Montanes','Montano','Monte','Montecillo','Montecinos','Montejano','Montelongo','Montemar','Montemayor','Monteon','Montero','Monterroso','Montesillo','Montesinos','Montesuma','Montez','Montiel','Montion','Montolla','Montoya','Montufar','Monzon','Mora','Morado','Moral','Morales','Morantes','Moras','Morelos','Moreno','Morentin','Morfin','Morgado','Morillo','Morin','Moriyo','Morones','Morquecho','Morras','Morua','Moscoso','Moso','Mosqueda','Mota','Motete','Mototl','Moxarro','Moxica','Moya','Moyeda','Moyotl','Muela','Mujica','Mulgado','Mundo','Munes','Mungia','Munguia','Munis','Munos','Murgo','Muriyo','Muro','Nabarro','Nabor','Nachi','Naco','Nagera','Naghi','Naghu','Nahuidzu','Nahuiyo','Najar','Najera','Nama','Namau','Namorado','Nanes','Napoles','Naquihui','Narbaes','Narvaez','Nasa','Nasayu','Natividad','Natuta','Navarrete','Naveda','Navia','Nayo','Nazario','Negreros','Negrete','Neira','Neri','Neria','Nesta','Neto','Nevares','Niave','Nicolaza','Niebes','Niebla','Nieva','Nieves','Nila','Nino','Noboa','Nocelotl','Noco','Nocuaa','Nocuiy','Nocusi','Nogales','Noghi','Nohuaco','Nohuidzu','Nohuiyo','Nolasco','Nollola','Noma','Nomau','Nopalera','Noquihui','Norabuena','Noriega','Nosa','Nosayu','Notario','Novoa','Noyo','Numau','Nuncio','Nunes','Nungarai','Nuno','Oballe','Obispo','Oblea','Obregon','Ocana','Ocaranza','Oceguera','Ochoa','Octavo','Ogalde','Olachia','Olaque','Olaya','Oldorica','Olea','Olgin','Olguin','Oliba','Olibares','Olibas','Olibera','Oliva','Olivas','Olivera','Olivo','Olivos','Olmos','Olveda','Onate','Oporto','Oranday','Ordaz','Ordones','Ordorica','Orduno','Oregel','Oria','Oribe','Orihuela','Orisava','Orocio','Orona','Oropesa','Orosco','Orsua','Orta','Ortes','Ortigosa','Ortis','Ortuno','Osegueda','Osorio','Ossorio','Osuna','Otero','Otuel','Oviedo','Oxeda','Ozegueda','Pablo','Pacho','Paderes','Padia','Padilla','Padron','Padua','Paes','Palacios','Palafos','Palasios','Palencia','Pallares','Palma','Palmerin','Palo','Paloalto','Paloblanco','Palomar','Palomeque','Palomera','Palomino','Palomo','Palos','Palula','Panecatl','Paneda','Paniagua','Pantaleon','Pantoja','Pantoxa','Para','Parada','Paramo','Pardave','Pardinas','Pardo','Pareja','Parra','Parrales','Parrilla','Partida','Pasillas','Pasqual','Pastrana','Patino','Patlan','Patricio','Patron','Paulin','Paura','Pavon','Paz','Pecina','Pedraza','Pedrosa','Peeres','Peguero','Peinado','Pelaes','Pelayo','Pena','Penalosa','Penilla','Penuelas','Perales','Peralta','Percino','Perea','Peredo','Peregrina','Pereira','Perez','Pescador','Pesina','Pestana','Pezina','Piceno','Pichardo','Picon','Piedra','Pilar','Piloto','Pimienta','Pineda','Pinon','Pinson','Pinto','Pintor','Pinzon','Pio','Pisa','Pisano','Pitones','Plancarte','Plasola','Plata','Plaza','Plazola','Pliego','Poblano','Poblete','Polanco','Polino','Polvo','Pompa','Ponse','Popoca','Porras','Portales','Portante','Portillo','Posada','Posas','Poso','Prada','Prado','Preciada','Preciado','Presas','Priego','Prieto','Proa','Procel','Provencio','Puebla','Puente','Puerta','Puga','Pulgarin','Pulido','Quebara','Quebas','Quebedo','Quenca','Queretano','Quero','Quesada','Quevedo','Quezada','Quijada','Quijano','Quijas','Quinones','Quintanar','Quintanilla','Quintano','Quintero','Quintos','Quiralte','Quirarte','Quiros','Quiteria','Quitl','Quixano','Rabadan','Rabago']
var sustantives=['Persona','Nombre','Varón','Hombre','Mujer','Abuelo','Padre','Madre','Hermano','Hermana','Hijo','Hija','Suegro','Nuera','Nieto','Sobrino','Viuda','Extraño','Huésped','Significado','Cabeza','Cabeza','Pelo','Ceja','Oído','Ojo','Nariz','Boca','Labio','Diente','Lengua','Mejilla','Mandíbula','Mentón','Barba','Cuello','Hombro','Brazo','Codo','Antebrazo','Mano','Mano','Uña','Seno','Ubre','Costilla','Regazo','Ombligo','Bajo Vientre','Vulva','Pene','Cojones','Culo','Nalga','Pierna','Pie','Rodilla','Rótula','Talón','Significado','Cuerpo','Cadáver','La Muerte','Piel','Piel','Hueso','Tendón','Carne','Sangre','Sangre','Médula','Glándula','Glándula','Pulmón','Corazón','Hígado','Bazo','Hiel','Lomos','Matriz','Intestinos','Intestinos','Excremento','Significado','Mente','Fuerza Vital','Alma','Sueño','Sudor','Lágrima','Dolor','Horror','Odio','Pecado','Copia','Significado','Sol','Luna/Mes','Estrella','Cielo/Nube','Luz','Espacio','Significado','Alba','Mañana','Día','La Tarde','Noche','Ayer','Significado','Año','Año','Primavera','Verano','Invierno','Significado','Viento Del Norte','Nieve','Granizo','Hielo','Niebla','Relámpago','Trueno','Significado','Entero','Parte','Significado','Tierra','Piedra','Diente','Monte','Campo','Estepa','Bosque','Fondo','Estanque','Charco','Marisma','Mar','Lago','Río','Agua','Espuma','Significado','Hoguera','Fuego','Humo','Polvo','Fuego','Significado','Árbol','Tallo','Hoja','Rama','Espina','Raíz','Resina','Cola','Significado','Roble','Roble','Haya','Fresno','Abedul','Arce','Aliso','Álamo Temblón','Tejo','Carpe','Olmo','Olmo','Tilo','Pino','Pino','Abeto','Avellana','Nuez','Manzana','Cereza','Nabo','Ajo','Baya','Mora','Tallo','Heno','Significado','Hormiga','Abeja','Avispa','Mosca','Pulga','Liendre','Vierme','Piojo','Vierme','Significado','Pez','Salmón','Serpiente','Serpiente','Concha','Pez','Significado','Ave','Águila','Cuervo','Tordo','Pato','Ganso','Gallo Silvestre','Golondrina','Grulla','Nido','Significado','Bestia','Animal Joven','Toro','Oso','Lobo','Verraco','Castor','Nutria','Ardilla','Erizo','Serpiente','Cría','Tortuga','Lince','Ratón','Zorro','Significado','Perro','Caballo','Animal De Arado','Vaca','Vaca','Toro','Cerdo','Puerco','Cabra','Cabra','Cabrío','Cabrito','Cabra','Oveja','Cordero','Cordero','Cornudo','Significado','Huevo','Miel','Miel','Leche','Leche','Manteca','Grasa','Cuero','Lana','Cuerno','Panal','Nata','Significado','Grano','Harina','Cebada','Cosecha','Cosecha','Trigo','Centeno','Cebada','Cebada','Avena','Judía','Guisante','Guisante','Cerveza','Cereal','Significado','Lino','Sal','Oro','Metal','Significado','Hacha','Arco','Pica','Gancho','Cuchillo','Herramienta','Azada','Bolsa','Tubo','Eje','Rueda De Molino','Rueda De Carro','Nave','Bastón','Rueda','Yugo','Arado De Palo','Significado','Casa','Morada','Techo','Viga','Esquina','Ángulo','Puerta','Valla','Carretera','Fuerte','Viga','Significado','Tribu','Gente','Pueblo','Gobernante','Poder','Ley','Saludo','Riqueza','Tarifa','Precio','Trifulca','Guerra','Victoria','Dios','Poder','Trabajo'];
var adjetives=['Despierto','Hermoso','Grande','Amargo','Muerto','Profundo','Sucio','Caro','Lejano','Rápido','Gordo','Lleno','Contento','Bueno','Feliz','Duro','Saludable','Pesado','Alto','Caliente','Largo','Nuevo','Cortés','Rico','Correcto','Áspero','Seguro','Mismo','Simple','Soltero','Fuerte','Alto','Grueso','Dormido','Feo','Pequeño','Dulce','Vivo','Superficial','Limpio','Barato','Cercano','Lento','Flaco','Delgado','Vacío','Triste','Malo','Apenado','Blando','Enfermo','Liviano','Bajo','Frío','Corto','Viejo','Grosero','Pobre','Equivocado','Suave','Liso','Peligroso','Diferente','Complejo','Casado','Débil','Bajo','Delgado'];

class Movie {
    constructor(name, director, year){
        this._name = name;
        this._director = director;
        this._year = year;
    }
}

var randomNamesDirector     = [];
var randomLastNamesDirector = [];
var randomFullNamesDirector = [];

var randomSustantivesMovies     = [];
var randomAdjetivesMovies = [];
var randomFullNamesMovies = [];

var randomDates     = [];
var randomNumber;

var movieList = [];


    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        randomNumber   = Math.floor(Math.random()*names.length);
        let name = names[randomNumber];
        
        randomNamesDirector.push(name);
    }
    // console.log(randomNamesDirector);



    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        randomNumber       = Math.floor(Math.random()*lastnames.length);
        let lastname = lastnames[randomNumber];
        
        randomLastNamesDirector.push(lastname);
    }
    // console.log(randomLastNamesDirector);



    
    for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        
        for (let j = 0; j < randomLastNamesDirector.length; j++) {
            var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*randomNamesDirector.length);
            let fullNameDirector = randomNamesDirector[randomNumber] + ' ' + randomLastNamesDirector[randomNumber];
            
            randomFullNamesDirector.push(fullNameDirector);
        }
    }
    // console.log(randomFullNamesDirector);



    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        randomNumber   = Math.floor(Math.random()*sustantives.length);
        let sustantiveMovie = sustantives[randomNumber];
        
        randomSustantivesMovies.push(sustantiveMovie);
    }
    // console.log(randomSustantivesMovies);


    
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        randomNumber       = Math.floor(Math.random()*adjetives.length);
        let adjetiveMovie = adjetives[randomNumber];
        
        randomAdjetivesMovies.push(adjetiveMovie);
    }
    // console.log(randomAdjetivesMovies);



    
    for (let i = 1950; i < 4000; i++) { //!!! VER ESTO puse infinity xq si genero 1000 pelis solo hay 69 desde 1950 a 2019
        var randomDate =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (2019 - 1950 + 1)) + 1950;
        
        randomDates.push(randomDate);
    }
    // console.log(randomDates);

    
    for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        
        for (let j = 0; j < randomAdjetivesMovies.length; j++) {
            var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*randomAdjetivesMovies.length);
            let fullNameMovie = randomSustantivesMovies[randomNumber] + ' ' + randomAdjetivesMovies[randomNumber];
            
            randomFullNamesMovies.push(fullNameMovie);
        }
    }
    // console.log(randomFullNamesDirector);


    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        var movieObj = new Movie(randomFullNamesMovies[i], randomFullNamesDirector[i], randomDates[i]);
        movieList.push(movieObj);
        console.log(movieList);
    }  




module.exports = {
    movieList:movieList,
};





var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var movieSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type:String, required: true, unique:true},
    director:String,
    year:Number
});

var Movie = mongoose.model('Movie', movieSchema);

module.exports = Movie;




//DEPENDENCIES
var namesGenerator = require('./namesGenerator');
var Movie = require('./models/Movie');

//OPERATIONS
//CREATE
function createMovies(){
    
    for (let i = 0;i < namesGenerator.movieList.length; i++){
        
        var movie = new Movie({
            name:namesGenerator.movieList[i]._name,
            director:namesGenerator.movieList[i]._director,
            year:namesGenerator.movieList[i]._year,
        });
        
        movie.save(function (err) {
            if (err) console.log(' there is an error: ' + err.message);
            console.log('movie ' + i + ' INSERTED');
            
        });
        
    }
}



//FIND
function findMovie(mensaje,callback){
    /**
    * Buscamos todos lo usuarios
    */
    console.log(mensaje); // hola
    Movie.find({}, function(err, data) {//devuelve usuarios
        if (err) throw err;
        // Objeto con todos los usuarios qeu han coincidido con la busqueda
        console.log(data);
        // callback()
    });
}

findMovie("hola", function(){
    // console.log("acabo");
});


// function findUserWithProyection(){
//     /**
//     * Buscamos los usuario que coincidan con el criterio de busqueda y usamos proyeccion para obtener solo el nombre
//     */
//     User.find({"name":"admin"},{"name":true}, function(err, user) {
//         if (err) throw err;
//         // object of all the users
//         console.log(user);
//     });
// }



module.exports = {
    createMovies:createMovies,
    findMovie:findMovie,
    // deleteMovies:deleteMovies,
};
```

Comment: ¿Puedes poner la salida del comando mongod?

Answer (score 1):

Para los que se encuentran con este problema aun.

Esto pasa cuando se han creado múltiples instancias de nuestra app y no se han cerrado completamente.

Para resolverlo solo es necesario cerrar todas las instancias de node o localizar la que este haciendo la conexión (que es mas difícil)

### En Windows

Se puede usar el administrador de tareas y finalizar todos los procesos

### En Linux

```
killall node
```

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo eliminar los procesos de node y mongo, luego levantes los servicios nuevamente

en linux puedes usar el método killall nombre_proceso

en windows usar el método TaskKill

Answer (score 0):

El error dice que no se puede conectar con mongodb, tal vez mongo no este corriendo, por lo regular debes iniciar mongodb manualmente ya que no es un servicio corriendo siempre en tu maquina, para verificar si esta corriendo puedes usar el comando

```
mongo status
```

si el proceso no esta corriendo debes arrancarlo usando el comando

```
sudo mongodb
```

ahora solo te pedirá tu contraseña y con eso debe poder conectarse